# Visual Studio 2005 - VC++ compiler C1001 on Windows 7

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, windows-7, c1001

When I try to build a simple "Hello World" C++ app on Windows 7 Beta, using Visual Studio 2005 (VC++2005) I get a rather generic error

> C1001 error (Internal compiler error)

The compiler seems to just crash, and Windows pops up its (un)helpful `This program has stopped working` dialog. The file it complains about is mcp1.cpp.

Has anyone come across this before?

Cheers,
Fritz

EDIT: The code is:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << "Hello!";
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT 2: I have installed SP1 as well as SP1 for Vista. VS popped up a warning saying it needs SP1 for Vista, but installing it makes no difference. No ideas about what I can possibly do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was the .NCB file included with the project - it was copied from a Windows XP setup, and after deleting that .NCB file, the project built fine under Windows 7 - no problems since.

Comment: Have the same problem, but unfortunately, this didn't fix it :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a generic error when the compiler encountered an unknown condition or crash.  It's a bug in the compiler, not your code.  Send the error report to MS so hopefully the issue can be fixed.  Try upgrading to SP1 of VS 2005 if you haven't already. or switch to 2008 if that is an option.

Beyonds that, we can't offer much help without seeing the code in question.

Comment: Thanks Michael - basically the code is the blank file you get when you create a new console app, with #include <iostream> at the top and std::cout << "hello!"; in main(). I have tried sending a bug report, but no answer. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Is it even supported on Windows 7? Check out the product information. For example, I went to the VS2005 Express edition [Readme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/hi-in/express/aa718403(en-us).aspx) and it lists only up to Vista in the Operating System list. You will have to check out depending on your exact setup.

Answer (score 0):

When I (up? down?) graded to Vista, VS 2005 had a long list of minor incompatibilities and annoyances.  All earlier versions were listed as unsupported (except for VB 6).  You may well have to upgrade VS versions.